# Getting handle on item in a pipe and piping result

Tags: pipe

I have this pretty cool command that giving me a nice json representation of a nix package

```
nix-env --json -qaA nixpkgs.wireshark | json_pp | less
```

But what I really want in pseudo shell/OCaml

```
nix-env --json -qaA nixpkgs.wireshark | json_pp | fun name -> name.json | less
```

I tried doing this with usages of `tee` with no success.

Comment: Do you mean you simply want to see occurrences of "fun name" replaced with "name.json" in the output of the `json_pp` call?

Comment: I am saying that right now less is getting the semantic equivalent of basically: less something    but I want it to be getting less something.json because then I can get syntax highlithing and whatnot.

Comment: Perhaps an example of the expected output of both commands would help us answer.

Comment: @dhag I want less to get a file that ends in json, i have right now the inmemory representation of the json coming from json_pp at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean something like `nix-env ... >name.json && less name.json`?

Comment: @dhag Ah, I guess that works too. is there a nice way to do this with just piping? Post that as an answer!

Comment: Answer posted, but I guess I don't understand why the file name is important. Does your version of less do something special when its input file name ends with `.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, something like the following should work:

```
nix-env --json -qaA nixpkgs.wireshark | json_pp >name.json && less name.json
```